# XCode tells me my .xcarchive is an Mac App but it is an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, ipad

I'm working with one of our clients to publish a new version of an iOS-App. The process here is, that an external agency builds the new version and sends me the .xcarchive. Then my part is, that I upload the app and prepare the store entry etc.

Since I'm the only one who is allowed to manage the client's account, I can't give the external agency access to it.

**The Problem:**
When I open the .xcarchive on my Mac, it always shows me, that it is an Mac OS-X App. I already asked the developers to check, that the build was created for iOS-Distribution.

I checked inside the apple developer account and the App-ID / Provisioning Profiles are all for iOS as well.

**My question:**
Is there anything that me or the developers should check again or something that we missed while creating that file? What and where can I define if the .xcarchive will be a Mac App or an iOS App?

Thanks to everyone that is willing to help me out.
Best regards,
Marius

Comment: Marius i think your developer providing wrong `.xcarchive` otherwise while you open any iOS `.xcarchive` it will show you iOS App `.xcarchive` in organiser in Xcode.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help :)